Should pre-determiners be capitalised in book titles?
Should a pre-determiner, such as 'all', be capitalised in a book's title or set as lower case?

I don't know a "pre-determiner" from a noun (I learned English grammar before this century; many terms have changed), but capitalization in book titles is a matter of style, not grammar rules.
In any case, I can't imagine a style that would not capitalize the word "All" in a book title.
Here are some examples from Google books. (Interestingly, the book graphics mostly use ALL CAPS in their title typography, because designers are afraid of capitalization too, it seems):
Here All Night
One for All: A Novel
It's All Under Control: A Journey of Letting Go, Hanging On
God Made All of Me: A Book to Help Children Protect Their Bodies
The Beautiful Music All Around Us
Not for All the Gold in Ireland (strange capitalization in the image, FYI)
Surmounting All Odds
